# Loading a .sys file into Immunity Debugger

Tags: immunity-debugger, driver

Can somebody tell me how to load a .sys file into Immunity Debugger correctly ?
Because when I load a driver into Imm. Debugger then I get the message that HAL.dll could not be found and that Imm. Debugger could not find the entry point.

I tried the solutins at [Loading a Driver in Immunity](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/loading-a-driver-in-immunity?rq=1) but that does not help.

I do not know what to do.

Best regards,

Comment: You got to use windbg ,install the driver/sys on a machine/vm and debug remotely...immunity/olly are ring 3 debuggers ,you need ring 0 debugger i.e. windbg...

Answer (score 1):

.sys extension is usually used for drivers. While they are the same PE executables, they run in kernel mode and thus use kernel-mode APIs exposed by the kernel executive itself ([ntoskrnl.exe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntoskrnl.exe)) or kernel-mode DLLs such as hal.dll. 
AFAIR someone made fake DLLs to simulate enough kernel APIs to achieve unpacking of drivers in user-mode debuggers like Olly but I don't have a link handy.